# How to populate recyclerview as the user scrolls down from sqlite database

Tags: java, android

How can I populate recyclerview from sqlite database as the user scrolls through the recyclerview. The data from the database are so many and it slow down the performance of the phone.

Is there away I can populate the recyclerview bit by bit instead of populating it at once?

Thanks in advance.

The recyclerview is working but due to the large amount of data to the recyclerview the app takes time to load.

DatabaseHelper

```
public ArrayList<AuthorInfo> getAuthorInfo() {
ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList() 
Sqlitedatabase dB;
dB = this.getReadableDatabase() ;
Cursor c = dB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table", null);
if (c.moveToFirst() ) {
    do {
AuthorInfo authorInfo = new AuthorInfo();
authorInfo.getName(c.getString(0));
authorInfo.getSubject(c.getString(0));
arraylist.add(authorInfo);
     } while (c.moveToNext()) 
  } 
   cursor.close();
   return arraylist;
}
```

MainActivity

```
...
ArrayList<AuthorInfo> authorInfo;
....

DatabaseHelper database = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext()); 
authorInfo = database.getAuthorInfo;
RecyclerviewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerviewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), authorInfo);
recyclerviewer.setAdapter(adapter); 

....
```

Comment: A common resolve in this case is to add a _"load more items"_ option as the last item in the list.  I imagine there may be better alternatives, though.

Comment: I do not understand. @Reilas

Comment: So, for example, you start the list with 10 items, and the 11th item will be a button to add 10 more items.

Comment: OK, let me try something with this idea